The square of the center of mass
In the book Classical Mechanics by Goldstein, there is an exercise related to the square of the position of the center of mass of a free particle. I must prove that
$$M^2R^2 = M\sum_i m_ir_i^2 - \frac12\sum_{i,j} m_im_jr_{ij}^2 \ ,$$
when $M$ and $R$ are the mass and the position of the center of mass, respectively.
My attempt:
I began with
$$(MR)^2 = \left(\sum_i m_ir_i\right)^2 = \sum_{i,j} m_im_jr_ir_j \ ,$$
but $r_j = r_i - r_{ij}$ and $\underline{r_i^2 - 2r_ir_{ij} = r_j^2 - r_{ij}^2}$. Then
\begin{align}
M^2R^2 &= \sum_{i,j}m_im_jr_i(r_i - r_{ij}) \\
       &= \sum_{i,j}m_im_j(r_i^2 - r_ir_{ij}) \\
       &= M\sum_{i}m_ir_i^2 - \sum_{i,j}m_im_jr_{ij}^2 + \boxed{\sum_{i,j}m_im_jr_ir_{ij}}.
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to eliminate the boxed term or if it is even possible.
Question:
Is there any relation that helps me to get what I want?

You have to be careful about vector algebra. $r_{ij}^2=r_i^2+r_j^2-2\mathbf{r_i}\cdot\mathbf{r_j}$

We have,
$$M^2R^2=M^2(R_x^2+R_y^2+R_z^2)=(MR)^2=\displaystyle\sum_i m_i^2r_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_j\left(\mathbf{r_i}\cdot\mathbf{r_j}\right)\tag{1}$$
where,
$$M^2R_x^2=\left(\sum_im_ix_i\right)^2=\displaystyle\sum_i m_i^2x_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jx_ix_j\tag{1.1}$$
$$M^2R_y^2=\left(\sum_im_iy_i\right)^2=\displaystyle\sum_i m_i^2y_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jy_iy_j\tag{1.2}$$
$$M^2R_z^2=\left(\sum_im_iz_i\right)^2=\displaystyle\sum_i m_i^2z_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jz_iz_j\tag{1.3}$$
Now,
$$r_{ij}^2=|\mathbf{r_{ij}}|^2=|\mathbf{r_i}-\mathbf{r_j}|^2=r_i^2+r_j^2-2\mathbf{r_i}\cdot\mathbf{r_j}\implies\mathbf{r_i}\cdot\mathbf{r_j}=\frac12\left(r_i^2+r_j^2-r_{ij}^2\right)\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}M^2R^2&=\displaystyle\sum_i m_i^2r_i^2+\frac12\left(\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jr_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jr_j^2-\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jr_{ij}^2\right)\\&=\sum_im_i^2r_i^2+\frac12\cdot2\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jr_i^2-\frac12\sum_{i\neq j}m_im_jr_{ij}^2\\&=\sum_jm_j\left(\sum_i m_ir_i^2\right)-\frac12\sum_{i,j}m_im_jr_{ij}^2\qquad\text{since } r_{ii}^2=0\\M^2R^2&=M\sum_i m_ir_i^2-\frac12\sum_{i,j}m_im_jr_{ij}^2\qquad\text{proved.}\end{aligned}$$
Thus,
$$\boxed{~ M^2R^2 = M\sum_i m_ir_i^2 - \frac12\sum_{i,j} m_im_jr_{ij}^2 ~}
$$
Hope this helps!
